# add Command programmatically to toolbar menu

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am programmatically creating new commands via [ICommandService](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fcommands%2FICommandService.html)#getCommand(String commandId) and am in need of adding these `Commands` to a `MenuManager`, but the `MenuManager` seems to accept only `IContributionItem` or `IAction` for its overloaded `add()` method

Seemingly the [CommandContributionItemParameter](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fmenus%2FCommandContributionItemParameter.html) can be constructed with the newly made `commandId`, and from it a `CommandContributionItem` can be made, and then added to the `MenuManager`

Is this the way to add programmatically created commands to a programmatically created `Toolbar`?

Any experience with this would be golden, thanks.

Comment: That looks reasonable. Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: I am having problems defining the Command, because I seem to be unable to find a way to construct a Category, and defining a command with a null Category is not possible. Maybe there's a Category factory somewhere?

Comment: Defining a command how? Commands are normally defined using the 'org.eclipse.ui.commands' extension point which deals with the category.

Comment: Yes, that is the usual XML way, and as pointed in the question I am programmatically doing that in this scenario. Command.define() is needed in order for the Command to be functional. The ICommandService.getCategory(String) is the one that creates the Category, and seemingly my command now works, but I must check if the Handler works...and I shall update.